# eBay API addItem returns error - <Item.Country> is invalid or missing

Tags: ebay-api

I'm totally new to ebay api. I tried to use addItem api call, I stopped with this error.
`

> **eBay returned the following error(s):**
>
> 37 : Input data is
> invalid.
> Input data for tag <Item.Country> is invalid or
> missing. Please check API documentation.

I've given all of their inputs and used their example (`addItem` code) only.

Site ID is 3 (UK) and `currencyID="GBP"`

Comment: Can you show your program? A sample code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the link http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/CountryCodeType.html.

Country Code for UK is `GB`.

So, your xml will be `<Country>GB</Country>`

Comment: and can please give me any link for working sample code to add an item  in ebay.

Comment: This tutorial should help - http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xML/docs/HowTo/index.html. Also, on developer.ebay.com, you can test your sample api calls. https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/Default.aspx.